# VHDL What does it mean when variable take a value immediately and signal take their value at the end of the process?

Tags: vhdl

I'm confused about a paragraph from my lab reading:
[Snippet from reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nswPQ.png)

```
Recall that variables like rst_meta take on their value immediately, whereas signals 
take on their assignment when the process suspends in this case, at the process sensitivity
list. This implies that the ordering of the signal assignments will change the  behavior of
the code.
```

I'm confused about what they mean by variables take their values immediately and signals take their value after the process. They also mentioned that whether a variable comes before or after a signal also makes a difference, but I don't know what effect that does.
Here's the code they tried to implement:
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKJ4r.png)

```
entity reset_bridge is
    Port ( clk_dst : in STD_LOGIC;
           rst_in : in STD_LOGIC;
           rst_out : out STD_LOGIC);
end reset_bridge;

architecture Behavioral of reset_bridge is
    --signal rst_meta : std_logic;
begin
    process (clk_dst,rst_in)
        variable rst_meta : std_logic;
    begin
        if rst_in = '1' then
            rst_meta := '1';
            --rst_meta <= '1';
            rst_out  <= '1';
        elsif rising_edge(clk_dst) then
            --rst_meta <= '0';
            rst_out <= rst_meta;
            rst_meta := '0';
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Edit:
The reading is on metastability and the circuit they're trying to implement is a double FF.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBNID.png)

Comment: Where are you to supposed to *recall* this from? That context should lead back to an authoritative source, which for VHDL would the the LRM (e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5 Signal assignment statement, 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement and 14.7 Execution of a model through 14.7.5.3 Simulation cycle. The latter tells us signals are updated in a simulation cycle prior to any process resumption and subsequent suspension. Available at the earliest in the next simulation cycle unless scheduled for a future simulation time. You can find Q & As here covering this by search.

Comment: The reading didn't really explain what rst_meta was, so I think that they're just trying to point out that rst_meta was a variable. The code is trying to implement a double FF since the reading was on metastability. I edited the question to include the picture of the circuit they want to implement.

Comment: The code contains syntax errors.  The question also seems confused.  Is this a question about vhdl mechanics or how to write a 2 flop synchronizer circuit in vhdl? They are two different questions likely answered many times previously on stackoverflow and the web in general.

Comment: To get a handle on the reason why : variables work (inside a process) like variables in a software language. But signals are the inter-process communication mechanism, and when communicating between processes, correct timings are necessary to avoid race conditions, deadlock, ambiguous ordering, etc. There are various strategies for this in software languages but none as clean or as safe as VHDL's signal semantics (possibly Ada's tasking comes close, but it's more complex)

Comment: For a general discussion of `signal` vs `variable` updating behavior, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68498392/why-wont-a-signal-be-updated-instantly-in-process-statement-vhdl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that saying, "This implies that the ordering of the signal assignments will change the behavior of the code" is accurate for your use case.

Consider the following code:

```
architecture Forward of AFewFlipFlops is
    signal r1, r2, r3: std_logic;
begin
    process (clk_dst)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_dst) then
            r1 <= A_in ;
            r2 <= r1 ;
            r3 <= r2 ;
            rst_out  <= r3;
        end if;
    end process;
```

The above creates the same hardware as:

```
architecture Reverse of AFewFlipFlops is
    signal r1, r2, r3: std_logic;
begin
    process (clk_dst)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk_dst) then
            rst_out  <= r3;
            r3 <= r2 ;
            r2 <= r1 ;
            r1 <= A_in ;
        end if;
    end process;
```

OTOH, if r1, r2, and r3 were variables, then architecture Reverse would produce the same results as the signal based architectures, but Forward would not - it would create only 1 flip-flop.  And it would not be due to the ordering of the signals, it would be due to the ordering of the variables.

If we consider a slightly different circuit, then we can see a variable being the invariant (as long as we are using it to create combinational logic) and here the signal ordering is important.

In architecture JunkySignalCode, if we change the order of the conditionals Add1 and Add2, then we impact the result as here last executed signal assignment wins.

```
architecture JunkySignalCode of JunkyMath is
    signal A : unsigned(7 downto 0) ;
begin
    process (clk_dst,rst_in)
    begin
       if rising_edge(clk_dst) then
         if rst_in = '1' then
             A <= (others => '0') ;
         else
           if Add1 = '1' then 
             A <= A + 1 ; 
           end if ; 
           if Add2 = '1' then 
             A <= A + 2 ; 
           end if ; 
         end if;
       end if;
    end process;
```

OTOH, in architecture JunkyVariableCode, if we change the order of the conditionals Add1 and Add2, then the result is indeed the same.

```
architecture JunkyVariableCode of JunkyMath is
    signal A : unsigned(7 downto 0) ;
begin
    process (clk_dst,rst_in)
      variable ATemp : unsigned(7 downto 0) ; 
    begin
       if rising_edge(clk_dst) then
         if rst_in = '1' then
            ATemp  := (others => '0') ;
         else
           if Add1 = '1' then 
             ATemp  := ATemp + 1 ; 
           end if ; 
           if Add2 = '1' then 
             ATemp  := ATemp + 2 ; 
           end if ; 
         end if;
         A <= ATemp ; 
       end if;
    end process;
```

One generality I see is that every signal assignment in a clocked process always creates a flip-flop.   Variable assignments in a clocked process may or may not create a flip-flop depending on the order of the assignments.

In JunkyMath, most of the time, the `if then end if` followed by `if then end if`  would be better understood as `if then elsif then end if`.  However, for the variable case here we ended up with an interesting exception to that rule.